# xml writer/editor -- use python's version?

Tags: python, xml

I need to learn/write XML and I already have python downloaded as I am also learning python. I did notice that there was another question on stackoverflow about xml writers and python but I didn't get the idea that there was real consensus on what's easiest to use?  That is, I would ideally like an XML editor that highlights my errors and helps with formatting as it can be very tedious. Should I stick with python's element tree xml app or download one of the following that I was told about? Thanks.

http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html
download Java SE and just use its editor

XML Notepad 2007 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&DisplayLang=en#AffinityDownloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use IntelliJ (community edition should be fine) and emacs for XML editing.

I used the Altova XMLSpy family back in the days I used windows.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Tillemans for your vote. I will keep them in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about two separate things.

XML Notepad and the NetBeans utility are apps for visually creating and editing XML.

Python's ElementTree is a library for programmatically creating and parsing XML.

Which one you need depends on what you want to do - create XML in an editor, or do it inside your program.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Roseman for such a clear answer! I have to ask though, how do most people create xml trees? By programmatically creating it or via something like XML Notepad or Netbeans utility? It would be good to know before downloading ..

Comment: You need both in practice. A good editor with xml support is really helpful, but to work with large datasets you need to automate. Hence you need both.